# Enable C++14 in QtCreator's [Clang]CodeModel

Tags: c++, qt-creator, c++14

How do I enable C++14 in the ClangCodeModel (or even the "normal" one)?

I added `CONFIG += c++14` in the `.pro` file and the project compiles fine with both `gcc` and `clang` but the IDE is annyoing me with spurious warnings on C++14 constructs.

When looking at the "C++ Code Model Inspector", the "Project Parts->General" tab says

> Language Version CXX11

despite the config entry. It seems the IDE's CodeModel does not pick that up.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Code Model.

Find the group "Clang Code Model Warnings" and "Copy" the current configuration ("Warnings for almost everything [built-in]" by default) in order to edit them.

In your new configuration add:

```
-std=c++14
```

to the end of the list of warnings and **restart** QtCreator. Just hitting apply or even refreshing the model does not work.

Afterwards the warnings should disappear. Let me know if it works!

*I'm using Qt Creator 4.0.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.*

Comment: It feels a bit hacky to do this but it seems to work. Nice idea nevertheless. In the long run I'd hope for actual support from QtCreator as this puts the language standard into the warning settings.

Comment: This doesn't work for versions >=4.5 as the flags are 'sanity checked' i.e. if they are not a warning specifier, they are removed.

Comment: @jaskmar : The only one I've found is to add a custom toolchain via Tools->Options->Kits->Compilers->Add->Custom and define all flags from the ground up. Alternatively, if you're stuck using an ancient GCC version like me, you can try writing a call-through script which appends `-std=c99` (in my case) to the command line and executes the actual compiler, and then add it via Add->GCC to spare yourself some trouble.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I think your comment is the answer. I've been Googling for ages, and this is the only things that works in Qt Creator 4.8.1 with a non-Qt C++ project.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Great, this worked for me to browse an imported "existing project" that doesn't use CMake or QMake. It was quite clunky though: After adding a custom toolchain with `-std=c++14` appended to the "Platform codegen options" I had to close and reopen the preferences window to actually use it in a "kit". Then Qt Creator had to be restarted.

Comment: @jaskmar Please create an answer to receive proper credit :)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because Qt Creator removes the non-warning flag automatically..

However if you have a CMake project you can just specify

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

and it will work (using QT Creator 4.7.1 here).

Comment: I unaccepted the other answer because it does not work anymore. However, this answer is not complete either, because it only works for CMake projects.

Comment: Yes I would have written a comment but I wasn't allowed to at that point because of missing karma.